# Is there a instagram module for magento to fetch images from either hastag or userid with filtering option

Tags: magento-1.9, module

The business requirement on my case is to filter from the feed. If it won't be the case i could have use `instafeed.js` to fetch post and show. But i couldn't find anything relevent to filtering from the backend before appearing on frontend ?

What i am looking for is, a module that will fetch images suppose all images with `#graduation` hastagged, and on backend, the admin will select which to show. Because people can tag anything inappropriate with the same tag then it will appear on frontend.

So before those feeds being posted on homepage, those which the admin will select will only appear.

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit more detailed what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello @AnnaVölkl, i have updated my question.

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html this plugin is having the filter functionality with user id and hashtag fetch images.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if asking for an extension recommendation is valid under the scope of this site, but you can take a look at this extension : http://magento.ikantam.com/store/free-instagram-magento-extension.html. It seems to provide what you are after.